# Accessing Object in Object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object

Hello I have a data fetching of Object from Object

Data

```
    {
  "test1": {
    "success": true,
    "mmr": 1627,
    "name": "Choo",
    "next_claim": 1639454954
  },
  "test2": {
    "success": true,
    "mmr": 1246,
    "name": "Dee",
    "next_claim": 1639454934
  },
  "test3": {
    "success": true,
    "mmr": 1066,
    "name": "Boo",
    "next_claim": 1639454964
  }
}
```

I can't seem to show them on the page

tried using

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react"
import Axios from "axios"

const Axie = () => {
  const [axieStats, setAxieStats] = useState({})

  const fetchAxie = async () => {
    const response = await Axios(
      "https://game-api.axie.technology/api/v1/ronin:0d771f9d749fe72671526e0a52ecdfc11f73ca7b,ronin:b9603b5ae4d10fce072432d99de572c1eb66b43e"
    )
    setAxieStats(response.data)
  }

  console.log(axieStats)
  useEffect(() => {
    fetchAxie()
  }, [])
  return <div></div>
}

export default Axie
```

can't seem to work

I have edited the question to the whole code from where I fetch the API.

Comment: Are you setting the value using the `setTest` method ? Also, remember that first, when it is an empty object test.test2 will throw an error

Comment: Would you mind if you could make a sandbox where you can show full code. If you like you can use https://codesandbox.io/ . This will make easier to understand what exactly is the problem.

Comment: Try: `<div>{JSON.stringify(axieStats)}</div>`  to see if theres a change in the object

Comment: still the same you can try to open the link in your tab so you can see the output @Woohaik

Comment: Im getting `'0x0d771f9d749fe72671526e0a52ecdfc11f73ca7b'` instead of `test1`

Comment: have you tried loggind the response before the `setAxieStats` to see if theres something

Comment: “I can't seem to show them on the page” You only use `axieStats` in a `console.log()`. It's not strange that it doesn't show up on your page if your render output is `<div></div>`.

Comment: @3limin4t0r because I'm trying to console it but it's object in object, when I try to show it on my div it doesn't show that's why i'm trying first

Comment: @PinkyPromise So does it show correctly when you `console.log(axieStats)`? How are you trying to display `axieStats` in your `<div>`? Do you get any JavaScript errors in the console?

Answer (score 0):

The `useState` hook as seen in your code is first initialized to an empty object, which is not the desired object you want to use in the first place. When you're trying to access `test2.mmr` on the empty object `test` it will not find that object and throw a null reference exception. Here are some things you can do to get to the state you need:

- Check that you're setting the data using the `setTest` function somewhere in your code.
- If the data doesn't exist locally (which is a common occurrence), then the call to fetch the data is asynchronous and you should have a `async-await` mechanism in place to handle updating the state variables for the dependent components.